# C# and Variable Scope in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, class, scope

Within a Winform app, I would like data in an instantiated class to be accessible by multiple form controls.

For example, if I create Class Foo, which has a string property of name, I'd like to instantiate Foo a = new a() by clicking Button1, and when I click Button2, I'd like to be able to MessageBox.Show(a.name).  There may be multiple instances of Foo, if that matters at all.

What is my best option for being able to use class instances in such a way?

Comment: Who is responsible for the instance of FOO? Can it be changed from multiple forms?

Comment: I'd like it to be accessible/changeable by multiple forms, sure.  I'm not sure who is responsible for FOO, as this is probably the answer to my question.  I'm not familiar enough with variable scopes while using winforms to answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A private field or property of a class satisfies the requirement - such field can be accessed by all methods of the class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        foo a;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a = new foo();
            a.name = "bar";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (a != null && a.name != null)
                MessageBox.Show(a.name);
            else 
                MessageBox.Show("");
        }
    }

    public class foo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

        public foo() { }
    }
}
```

If you want this variable to be accessible to other forms you'd need to make it public (preferably as property) - [C# winform: Accessing public properties from other forms & difference between static and public properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663710/c-sharp-winform-accessing-public-properties-from-other-forms-difference-betwe)

Comment: His second requirement is that `a` be available from different forms. EDIT: Or Not?

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  I was able to create a class, and instantiate a List<myClass> within the form scope, and it is accessible by all form objects.  Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: Chaos, while I WOULD like it to be, it is not a necessity.  Any further information that would make it accessible by multiple forms would be great.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you just want a static class

Comment: Would a static class be suitable in cases where I need multiple instances of the class?  I will be opening up several files, and parsing out the relevant information into various properties of the class.  I figured a static class would only be suitable if I was not working with several instances.

Answer (score 0):

Winforms are nothing but some graphical elements backed by code. The code can own/create objects just like regular 'non-winform' code. The same scoping rules apply.

My guess if yours is more a problem of 'how does my form access shared state defined outside of it'? Create a static class, or have a setter on the class of your form that other code can use to set this shared state.

Answer (score 0):

A form you create is just another class, derived from `Form`. A class exists in a given namespace, so you just need to create your `Foo` class in a namespace shared by your application's forms.

If a class is shared by multiple forms, then usually you'd separate out that class into a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet [C# MVP] 
Guest   Posts: n/a

## 2: May 15 '07

re: Application variables in csharp.

---

On May 15, 12:04 pm, Control Freq 
wrote:
Quote:
Still new to csharp. I am coming from a C++ background.
>
In C++ I would create a few top level variables in the application
class. These are effectively global variables which can be accessed
throughout the application because the application object is known.
>
What is the csharp equivalent of this practice?
I can't seem to add variables to the "public class Program" class and
get access to them from other files.
>
I am probably missing something obvious. 
Basically you want public static fields (or preferably properties).

An alternative to this is a singleton:
http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/singleton.html

Jon

When in doubt, find something signed by John Skeet. Found on: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/646865-application-variables-csharp