# C# winform: Accessing public properties from other forms & difference between static and public properties

Tags: c#, winforms, public

I am trying to understand whats the difference between a static and public properties. But when I tried to access my public property 'Test' in other form it says 'null'.

Heres Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string _test;

    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set { _test = value; }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _test = "This is a test";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

Here's Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        label1.Text = frm1.Test;
    }
}
```

To check the value of 'Test' in Form1, I put a breakpoint to this line:

```
label1.Text = frm1.Test;
```

But the value is 'null'.

Please help me how can I access public properties to other forms.

And BTW I tried to make this public property be a 'public static'. I can access this using this:

```
Form1.Test
```

But I noticed that I can change 'Test' value from Form2 which I don't want to happen. That's why I am trying to use public property but with no luck. Can somebody clarify me these things. Thanks for all your help guys!

```
EDIT: (For follow up question)
```

Sir John Koerner's answer is the best answer for my question. But I have a follow up question, I tried to make these 'test' properties to be a 'static', and I noticed that even if I make this property a static or public property, it still can be edit in Form2. To make myself clear here's a sample:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 f1;
    public Form2(Form1 ParentForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        f1 = ParentForm;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = f1.Test;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f1.Test = "This test has been changed!";

        this.Close();
    }
}
```

After Form2 closed, I tried to break again in Form1_Load to check value of 'Test', and it was changed! How can I make a public property in Form1 to readOnly in Form2 and cannot be editted? Please clarify to me. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your property is an instance variable, so the value can be different across different instances of `Form1`.

If you are trying to access instance variables from a parent form, the easiest way to do that is to pass Form1 in to the constructor of Form2.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 f1;
    public Form2(Form1 ParentForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        f1 = ParentForm;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = f1.Test;
    }
}
```

Then when you create a new Form2 from Form1, you can do this:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
```

If you want your property to be read only, you can simply not specify a setter:

```
public string Test
{
    get { return _test; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this man, please see my edit for my follow up question, I hope I made my question clear.

Comment: that's it! thanks for your help John! Nice lesson from you! Sorry for being a newbie :(

Answer (score 1):

Use of this method 'static'

At first Control label property Modifiers=Public

in Program code below

```
public static Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
public static Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
```

in Form1 code below

```
Program.frm2.show();
```

in Form2 code below

```
label1.Text=Program.frm1.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `frm1` not your main form object. It is newly created object where property `Test` initializes when it loads (in `Form1_Load` event handler).

Answer (score 0):

The first instance of `Form1` shows an instance of `Form2`, and then `Form2` creates *another* instance of `Form1`. This could work, but you set `_test` in the [`Form.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event, which:

> Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.

You do not show the instance of `Form1` you're trying to read `Test` from, so its `Load` event will not occur and `Test` remains `null`.

You could add a constructor overload or property to pass the Form1 reference as @JohnKoerner mentions, but I would prefer to only pass the required variable, perhaps even encapsulated in an event, to reduce coupling. `Form2` usually doesn't need to know all about `Form1`.

Answer (score -1):

***public***

The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.

***static***

The static modifier on a class means that the class cannot be instantiated, and that all of its members are static. A static member has one version regardless of how many instances of its enclosing type are created.

A static class is basically the same as a non-static class, but there is one difference: a static class cannot be externally instantiated. In other words, you cannot use the new keyword to create a variable of the class type. Because there is no instance variable, you access the members of a static class by using the class name itself.

However, there is a such thing as a static constructor. Any class can have one of these, including static classes. They cannot be called directly & cannot have parameters (other than any type parameters on the class itself). A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced. Looks like this:

static class Foo()
{
    static Foo()
    {
        Bar = "fubar";
    }

```
public static string Bar { get; set; }
```

}

Static classes are often used as services, you can use them like so:

MyStaticClass.ServiceMethod(...);