# Can't figure what's wrong with my code

Tags: c#, winforms

First, sorry for my English, it's not my first language.
I'm on the first grade of high school, and at my college we have a certificate program of three years in system analysis and development, along with the normal classes. 
We are just starting learning c# at the course, but since we have some free time at the lab we started "playing" with winforms. I prefer to look at the code or google the error instead of asking, but this time i really can't figure what's wrong.

When i was using only one form, to get the input and show all users' information in real time (without a combobox, just labels), it all worked fine. What I want to do is, take input of five users, and , if the fields are filled correctly, add the first name of the user as an item to the combobox, and he can see the name/sex/age of previous users browsing the combobox items.

The Form1's code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        variaveis.i++;
        variaveis.nome[variaveis.i] = textBox1.Text;
        variaveis.sobrenome[variaveis.i] = textBox2.Text;
        variaveis.sexo[variaveis.i] = comboBox1.Text;
        if (textBox3.Text != null)
            variaveis.idade[variaveis.i] = textBox3.Text;
        double num;
        bool isnum = double.TryParse(variaveis.idade[variaveis.i], out num);

        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Update();
        if (variaveis.nome[variaveis.i]!=null && variaveis.sobrenome!=null && variaveis.idade[variaveis.i] != null && isnum)
        {              
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            comboBox1.Refresh();
            frm2.comboBox1.Items.Add(variaveis.nome[variaveis.i]); //Only works with the first input
            if (variaveis.i == 1)
            {
                frm2.Show();
                frm2.Location = new Point(this.Left + this.Width, this.Top);
                frm2.Height = this.Height;
                frm2.label6.Text = variaveis.nome[variaveis.i];
                frm2.label7.Text = variaveis.sobrenome[variaveis.i];
                frm2.label8.Text = variaveis.sexo[variaveis.i];
                frm2.label9.Text = variaveis.idade[variaveis.i]; 

            }







        }
        else
        {
            variaveis.i--;
            MessageBox.Show("Preencha todos os campos",
   "Erro");
        }
        if (variaveis.i >= 5)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        comboBox1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

The Form2's code:

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label6.Text = variaveis.nome[comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1]; // i don't even know if i can use an array like this
        label7.Text = variaveis.sobrenome[comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1];
        label8.Text =variaveis.sexo[comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1];
        label9.Text = variaveis.idade[comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1];
    }
```

The variables class (I thought would be easier to work this way if I'm using multiple forms, if I'm wrong, correct me):

```
 class variaveis
{
    public static string[] nome = new string[5]; //name
    public static string[] sobrenome = new string[5]; //last name
    public static string[] sexo = new string[5]; //gender
    public static string[] idade = new string[5]; //age(string, checked with tryparse)
    public static int i = 0;
}
```

Sorry if it's a noob question or if the error is obvious, but I started working with WinForms a couple weeks ago.

EDIT:
So the problems now are:
-Sometimes the program throw me the error even when all conditions are apparently fulfilled.

-Can't add items to a combobox in another form. Tried this:

```
    public void AddItem(object item)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(variaveis.nome[variaveis.i]);
    }
```

Calling it in Form1:

```
frm2.AddItem(variaveis.nome[variaveis.i]);
```

The syntax seems correct, but nothing happens.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please describe the error as exactly as possible.

Comment: your class `variaveis` is designed in the way of `assembly`. Why don't you just use Properties for it? It's much more readable and maintainable and it's how we do in high-level OOP programming languages.

Comment: You are declaring frm2 twice, also I would create public properties on Form2 instead of relying on the controls being public

Comment: @germi sometimes it gives me the error("fields are not filled correctly") even wen all conditions(inside if) were apparently fulfilled

Comment: @MarkHall oh thanks, i forgot to delete it after editing the code

Comment: @MarkHall if its what i thinking, tried this(5th answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663710/c-sharp-winform-accessing-public-properties-from-other-forms-difference-betwe , and get the error "form2 does not contain a constructor and that takes 0 arguments", and if i add the "this": "Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

If you set it up like this, i think it is easier to address your data.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public string Sobrenome {get; set;}
    public string Sexo {get; set;}
    public string Idade {get; set;}
}

public class Variaveis
{
  public Person[] People {get; set;}
  public Variaveis
  {
    People = new Person[5];
  }
}
```

Now you can access the data like so:

```
var myName = Variaveis.People[2].Nome;
```

Comment: Your example doesn't compile.  Plus, you are accessing Variaveis as though it were a static class, and yet you didn't declare it as a static class with static variables.

Answer (score 0):

I edited some things and solved the "if" problem . The new code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string[] nome = new string[5];
    public string[] sobrenome = new string[5];
    public string[]  sexo = new string[5];
    public string[] idade = new string[5];
    public int i = 1;





    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private void label9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
        nome[i] = textBox1.Text;
        sobrenome[i] = textBox2.Text;
        sexo[i] = comboBox1.Text;
        idade[i] = textBox3.Text;
        double num;
        bool isnum = double.TryParse(idade[i], out num);


        if (textBox1.Text !=null && textBox2.Text!=null && textBox3 != null && isnum == true)
        {                
            frm2.comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
            frm2.comboBox1.Update();
            comboBox1.Update();
            textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(i); // just to check the variable's value, since they dont appear in the debugger tool
            if (i == 1)
            {
                frm2.Show();
                frm2.Location = new Point(this.Left + this.Width, this.Top);
                frm2.Height = this.Height;
            }
            frm2.label6.Text = nome[i];
            frm2.label7.Text = sobrenome[i];
            frm2.label8.Text = sexo[i];
            frm2.label9.Text = idade[i];
            frm2.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = frm2.comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();                
            ++i;
        }

         if(isnum == false && textBox1.Text == null && textBox2.Text == null && textBox3 == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Preencha todos os campos", "Erro");
        }

        if (i >= 5)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        comboBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I've noticed that all controls(not just combobox1) only respond to the first command coming from another form. If i put a textbox in form2 and call:

```
frm2.textBox1.Text = i;
```

it's going to show "1" forever. How do i solve this?

Comment: please don't post follow-ups to your own questions unless it is an answer; just edit your original post if you want to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by myself, by adding this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 f1;
    public Form2(Form1 f1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.f1 = f1;
```

This:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 frm2;
```

and this:

```
public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        frm2 = new Form2(this);


    }
```

The complete code with some improvements:

Form1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 frm2;
    public string[] nome = new string[6];
    public string[] sobrenome = new string[6];
    public string[]  sexo = new string[6];
    public string[] idade = new string[6];
    public int i = 0;






    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        frm2 = new Form2(this);


    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ++i; 
        nome[i] = textBox1.Text;
        sobrenome[i] = textBox2.Text;
        sexo[i] = comboBox1.Text;
        idade[i] = textBox3.Text;

        double num;
        bool isnum = double.TryParse(idade[i], out num);


        if (textBox1.Text !=null && textBox2.Text!=null && textBox3 != null && isnum == true)
        {
            frm2.comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
            frm2.comboBox1.Update();
            comboBox1.Update();
            if (i == 1)
            {
                frm2.Show();
                frm2.Location = new Point(this.Left + this.Width, this.Top);
                frm2.Height = this.Height;
            }
            frm2.label6.Text = nome[i] + " "  + sobrenome[i];
            frm2.label8.Text = sexo[i];
            frm2.label9.Text = idade[i];
            frm2.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = frm2.comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();                
        }

         if(isnum == false && textBox1.Text == null && textBox2.Text == null && textBox3 == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Preencha todos os campos", "Erro");
            --i;
        }

        if (i >= 5)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        comboBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 f1;
    public Form2(Form1 f1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.f1 = f1;
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Usuários");
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            label6.Text = f1.nome[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] + " " + f1.sobrenome[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
            label8.Text = f1.sexo[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
            label9.Text = f1.idade[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            label6.Text = " ";
            label8.Text = " ";
            label9.Text = " ";
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help anyway.